# Contador Progressivo

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estou tentando fazer um contador progressivo no estilo do Impostômetro, porém é uma quantidade não monetária, apenas uma unidade. No momento este é meu código:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Teste Contador</title>
</head>
<script src="vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<body onload="startCountdown()">
    <?php
        date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
        $n = 180000;
        $cur_time = time();
        $orig_time = strtotime("2019-02-18 9:00:00");
        $x = $n + ceil((abs(time() - strtotime("2019-02-18 9:23:00"))) / (533 + 1/3));
    ?>
    <script>
        var g_iCount = new Number();
        var g_iCount = <?= $x ?>;
        function startCountdown(){
            if((g_iCount - 1) >= 0){
                g_iCount = g_iCount + 1;
                numberCountdown.innerText = g_iCount;
                setTimeout('startCountdown()',1000);
            };
        };
    </script>
    <div class="numberCountdown">
        <div id="numberCountdown"></div>
    </div>
    <style>
        .numberCountdown {
            color: #0000ff;
        }
    </style>
</body>
```

Os problemas que estou enfrentando são:
1- Gostaria de não utilizar o "onload='startCountdown()'" na tag "body";
2- Queria colocar um filtro de centena, milhar, milhões, etc.(123.456.789);
Qualquer falta de informação só falar que eu edito a postagem o mais cedo possível.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Basta adicionar a tag `script` depois das `div`s
2. Use `match` para separar de 3 em 3 e o `join` para unir com o `.`

Código:

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
    $n = 180000;
    $cur_time = time();
    $orig_time = strtotime("2019-02-18 9:00:00");
    $x = $n + ceil((abs(time() - strtotime("2019-02-18 9:23:00"))) / (533 + 1/3));
?>
<div class="numberCountdown">
    <div id="numberCountdown"></div>
</div>
<style>
    .numberCountdown {
        color: #0000ff;
    }
</style>
<script>
    let g_iCount = <?php echo $x; ?>;
    function startCountdown(){
        if((g_iCount - 1) >= 0){
            g_iCount++;
            numberCountdown.innerText = g_iCount.toString().match(/[0-9]{1,3}/g).join('.');
            setTimeout(startCountdown, 1000);
        };
    };
    startCountdown();
</script>
```

Comment: Por algum motivo ele está adicionando de 2 em 2.

Comment: Edit1: Era erro meu, estava puxando a função duas vezes.

Comment: Se minha resposta resolveu seu problema clique no botão ✓ ao lado dela para aceita-la